# Extend twig-loader with custom functions

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, webpack, twig

I'm using [`twig-loader` package](https://github.com/zimmo-be/twig-loader) within a Symfony 5 application that runs Encore (webpack).
While trying to load a template via the `twig-loader`, I would like to extend the `twig.js`-functionality (which is used by the loader package).

So, basically, I need this to run:

```
// webpack.config.js
Encore.
  ...
  .addLoader({
      test: /\.twig$/,
      loader: 'twig-loader',
  })
  ...
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();


// somewhere in my js-file
const template = require('./form.html.twig');
template({
  'label': 'Some label',
});


// And the twig-file:
<form method="post" action="{{ path('example_route', {'some': 'parameter'}) }}">
    <button>{{ label }}</button>
</form>
```

The error I get, when rendering the above is, that the `path`-function is not known by twig.js:

```
Twig.Error {message: "path function does not exist and is not defined in the context", name: "TwigException", type: "TwigException", file: "$resolved:3132…b7d2:form.html.twig"}
```

Is there any way, I can [extend the `twig.js` functionality](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/wiki/Extending-twig.js#functions) globally, so that `twig-loader` uses my extended `twig.js` package?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm trying to do the same only with twig.js and I'm surprised a important function like path is not even known by it. Did you extend the twig.js with `extendFunction` to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the templates populated at runtime on the browser, and the path() function in twig is a server-side function (from the Router component), path won't work as you expect.

Since your path is static, though, there's an easy solution: pass it to the template as a variable, passing it from server-side twig, e.g.

```html
<div id='my_data' data-example-path='{{ path('example_route') }}'></div>
```

If you use stimulus, even better, you can pass it to the controller as a variable.

If you need dynamic paths, use fosjsrouting bundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), then create the path in your js file, then pass that route to the twig renderer as before.

There's no way to implement path() in twig.js, because it doesn't have access to routing table.